# Check how many times a string is contained in a string in Applescript

Tags: applescript

So I want to set a variable (in this case `numberOfContains`) to the times that `theString2` is contained in `theString`.

```
set theString to "hello world"
set theString2 to "l"
set numberOfContains to (times theString2 appears in theString) 
--This doesn't work, it's just a way of showing what I want my code to do
return numberOfContains --this should return 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an Apple Script expert, but you could try the following:

```
set theString to "hello world"
set theString2 to "l"
set text item delimiters to theString2
set textItems to text items of theString
set nrOfTextItems to number of items of textItems
set numberOfContains to nrOfTextItems - 1
```

`numberOfContains`  will be 3.

Comment: As 'textItems' is a list, you can simplify line 5 with 'set nrOfTextItems to count of textItems' — 'length' would also work instead of 'count'. Of course, you could also eliminate the last line by appending '- 1' to line 5.

Comment: @Mockman Thanks for your comment, I interpreted your answer as removing line 6 and replacing line 5 with `set numberOfContains to (number of (items of textItems)) - 1`

Comment: `set nrOfTextItems to (count of textItems) - 1`

Comment: @Mockman How exactly does swapping out **`number of...`** for **`count`** _"simplify"_ the line ?  I think you've got an exceedingly low threshold for what you' appear to be defining to be more complex.  **`number of...`** is (in this case) fine.

Comment: One method gets the items and then counts them. The other just counts the list. There is no reason to get into the items.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is Regular Expression

```
use AppleScript version "2.5"
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set theString to "hello world"
set theString2 to "l"
set regex to current application's NSRegularExpression's regularExpressionWithPattern:theString2 options:0 |error|:(missing value)
set numberOfContains to (regex's numberOfMatchesInString:theString options:0 range:{location:0, |length|:(count theString)}) as integer
```